# How to get lines that have one of the required values in a particular column?

Tags: text-processing

Is there a way to get lines that have one of the required values in a particular column.
For example if there is one file like this

```
12 a 4
11 f 5
8  b 6
10 x 7
```

and another file with a list of values, for example

```
a
b
x
```

Is there a way to get only those lines from file 1 that have one of the values of file 2 in the 2nd column. Like in this case, output should be:

```
12 a 4
8 b 6
10 x 7
```

Thanks in advance.
My files are tab delimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
$ cat file1 
12      a       4
11      f       5
8       b       6
10      x       7
```

and

```
$ cat file2 
a
b
x
```

you can use a brief AWK script:

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR {strings[$0]} NR > FNR && ($2 in strings)' ./file2 ./file1
12      a       4
8       b       6
10      x       7
```

The first pattern (`FNR == NR`) is only true for `file2` (the first file argument on the command line); the corresponding action populates an associative array whose indexes are the strings to match.

The second pattern (`NR > FNR && ($2 in strings)`) is only true for lines coming from `file1` (and from any other file that may follow on the command line), *if* the second column is an index of the `strings` array. The corresponding action is omitted, defaulting to `print`.

To allow the strings to be looked up to also contain spaces, assuming the columns in `file1` are separated by a single `<tab>`, you can add the `-v FS='\t'` (or `-F '\t'`) option to your `awk`'s invocation.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this script to get opposite output? That is to get the lines of file1 for which column 2 doesn't contain values from from file2. The output in that case would be: 11   f     5

Comment: @Arsala Sure, just change `($2 in strings)` into `!($2 in strings)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
grep -wf file2 file1
```

The `f` matches the contents of file 2 and the `w` will make sure that only whole words maching the contents of file 2 are matched from the contents of file 1 so that strings like `aa` and `ab` and `apple` aren't matched.

Verified with GNU grep.

Comment: Since the file 2 contents are plain strings, you could add the `-F` option.

Answer (score 0):

For 3 fields in `file1.txt`, and single character matching from `file2.txt`:

```
chars="$( tr -d "\n" <file2.txt)"
regexp="\t[$chars]\t"
eval grep -E "$regexp" file1.txt
```

**Untested**

Comment: Why `eval`? It doesn't seem necessary. Also, `\t` doesn't match a tab in BRE or ERE, while it does in PCRE, so it won't work unless grep supports that flavor and is invoked in a suitable way (e.g. GNU grep invoked as `grep -P`).

Comment: It didn't give me any output.